# how return keyword work in main function or any user defined function?

Tags: c, embedded, embed

what basis that does function return 0 or 1 o especially in main()?
is it possible that -1 is the return value?

Comment: What are you asking? it doesn't make any sense. If your function has a return type, it must return a value, if it doesn't AFAIK it's undefined behavior, and I bet your compiler can warn about a function that should return a value but doesn't.

Comment: Look at the function prototype or definition.

Comment: @user236841 As for me then I do not know whether a function return a value or not.:)

Comment: please reopen the question ,now I improved and edit the questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By placing `void` in front of any function definition, you make it so that the function does not need to return a value. For example:

```
void test(void)
{
    ...
}
```

Would not `return` anything.

Comment: Unless it is a void pointer (void *)

Comment: @Deanie : `void*` is clearly not the same as `void` so really not "unless" anything.

Comment: @Clifford Obviously the person asking has no knowledge of void * either.  Telling him that a function starting with void doesn't return anything can be very misleading.